# Transience of Brownian Motion

Tags: probability, measure-theory, brownian-motion

I am reading a book by Morters & Peres on Brownian motion, and I got really confused with the definition of transience.
At first, they give a simple definition that BM is transient if it converges to infinity almost surely. Then it comes to occupation measures, and they prove the following result:

Let U be a bounded open subset of $\mathbb{R}^d$, and x $\in \mathbb{R}^d $ arbitrary.

$\bullet$ If $d=2$, then $\mathbb{P}_x$ -almost surely $\int_{0}^{\infty}\mathbb{1}_U B(t)dt = \infty$.

$\bullet$ If $d\geqslant3$, then $\mathbb{E}_x \int_{0}^{\infty}\mathbb{1}_U B(t)dt < \infty$.

But after that, they say the following: "In case Brownian Motion is transient it is interesting to ask further for the expected time the process spends in a bounded open set. In order not to confine this discussion to the case $d\geqslant3$ we introduce suitable stopping rules in $d=2$."
And then they give a definition that I find totally confusing:

Suppose that $ B(t): 0\leqslant t \leqslant T $ is a d-dimensional brownian motion and one of the following three cases holds:

(1): $d\geqslant 3$ and $ T = \infty $

(2) $d\geqslant 2$ and T is an independent exponential time with parameter $ \lambda > 0 $

(3) $d\geqslant 2$ and T is the first exit time from a bounded domain D.

The convention is that $D = \mathbb{R}^d$ in cases (1), (2). We refer to the three cases by saying that $ B(t): 0\leqslant t \leqslant T $ is a $\textbf{transient}$ brownian motion.

Would you please explain to me why do we need such a separation into three cases? I guess the result that I stated provides some motivation for it, but I still don't understand why do we have exactly these 3 cases. Why exponential time? Why do we divide into $d\geqslant 3$ and $d\geqslant 2$, and not $d\geqslant 3$ and $d = 2$, for example? I find it all really confusing. Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: In $d=2$ the calculation in case 1 would just give infinity. Cases 2 and 3 provide interesting cutoff times that make it so you do not just get infinity. One could also use a deterministic finite time or something like that.

Comment: Also, cases 2 and 3 are still of some interest even when $d>2$.

Comment: Dear @Ian, thank you for your response. I think I got some intuition for cases (1) and (3). In case (1), we can think about infinity as a "point" added to R^n, and BM hits it with probability 1. In case d>=2, the boundary of a bounded domain also has probability 1 of being hit, thus in some sense the two stopping times are similar. I still have no intuition for (2), but I guess it has something to do with Markov Processes, which I have never studied.